# ASP.NET GridView & SqlDataSource FilterExpression - Column name with hash / pound symbol

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, filter, datasource

I am working with a brilliantly designed table, where the primary key column contains a #: OTTXN#

I need to be able to select and display these values in the GridView which is populated from my SqlDataSource, which is working fine.

When i add FilterExpression=" = '{0}'"  then the code craps out on me, because the column name has a hash tag / pound symbol in it.

I'm able to alter the select statement to use an alias without the pound symbol, but SQL where clauses dont allow you to use a column alias.

Any way i can get this to work?

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="dsIseries">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OTTXN#" HeaderText="OTTXN" 
                SortExpression="OTTXN#" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OTWODT" HeaderText="OTWODT" 
                SortExpression="OTWODT" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OTBAD1" HeaderText="OTBAD1" 
                SortExpression="OTBAD1" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsIseries" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VM520ConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VM520ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
            SelectCommand='SELECT ottxn#, otwodt, otbad1
                            FROM kivalib.ortxnpf
                            fetch first 100 rows only'
            FilterExpression=" = '{0}'">
        <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" />
        </FilterParameters>    
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

---

EDIT

Without making changes to the database... is there a way i could query the columns from the code-behind and pass the results back to the SqlDataSource or GridView with the values & altered column name?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a VIEW in the DB that includes all the relevant columns with better names and then query from that view.

Comment: Great idea, but unfortunately I don't have that option. It's a DB2 database and I don't have authority to alter it.